# Ajuda - Why is voting important?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

No link de ajuda o titulo do tópico "Why is voting important?" não foi traduzido.

Answer (score 2):

Telas:

Título

[image: titulo]

Índice

[image: índice]